# Extracting data from an excel sheet into another excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a sheet with certain data arranged like this:

```
X8 - something - something2
X12 - somethingelse - asdfg
X8 - asft - sastaryraavt
X8 - random - random2
```

I need to extract only and all of the rows labeled `X8` to another sheet inside the Excel spreadsheet. So for the above example, the second sheet would look exactly the same but would be missing the 2nd row labeled `X12`.

How would one go about doing this?

EDIT: I would like it to be more like a function and not require copy-and-paste or such. For example, if one value is changed in the parent spreadsheet, say the "something" in the first X8 row, the change should also automatically mirror over to the child spreadsheet (the one containing only X8 rows).

EDIT 2: I just figured out how to *mirror* my parent sheet to the new sheet using  `=IF(OFFSET(Form!$A$1,ROW(C14)-1,COLUMN(C14)-1)=0,"",OFFSET(Form!$A$1,ROW(C14)-1‌​,COLUMN(C14)-1))`.  I'm still confused on **how to delete rows (like not just make empty, completely delete) that contain a certain word**, say, `X12`. Additionally, I'm using Google Spreadsheets so I don't think I can input code like `Sub` etc and am relying only on native formulas.

Comment: You could sort everything, and then all the X8 would be together and then all you need is a single cut and paste.

Comment: Oops, it turns out I wasn't specific :) edited

Comment: Update: I am using `=IF(OFFSET(Form!$A$1,ROW(C14)-1,COLUMN(C14)-1)=0,"",OFFSET(Form!$A$1,ROW(C14)-1,COLUMN(C14)-1))` to mirror my new sheet as the old one. How can I delete the rows with anything but "X8"?

Comment: This will give you useful tips, I tried it myself already.http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/12/09/multiple-occurrences-lookup-and-extraction/
For a more serious version:
http://thinketg.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to copy/mirror the spreadsheet, but I still need to know how to **delete** rows that have "X12" or whatever in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use Google Sheets, then the following won't work, but I'll offer as much (since this question was tagged for Excel), just in case it helps you or others that need to mirror content conditionally to another sheet like this.

Using Excel, once you have your source data on your first sheet (regardless of whether this is a 'Table'), position cursor in data/table area and from **Data** ribbon, select **From Table** (in the **Get & Transform** section). This will open a query editor (looks like PowerQuery). From here, you can complete whatever transformations or selections you need to filter or re-arrange or wrangle your data. So you could filter by your first column, in your case. But note you can do quite a lot more here (adding new calculated columns, re-arranging columns, removing columns, etc.). When done, select **Close & Load** in the **Home** ribbon. Then select **New Sheet**.

Now when you make changes to your source sheet table, the Query you created will handle the required selection and transformation to mirror to the other sheet. Note to see changes, you'll need to click **Refresh** on the **Data** ribbon. You can also schedule automatic refreshes if desired. Click **Connections** from the **Data** ribbon, then select your Query and click **Properties**.

Again, sadly this won't work in Google Sheets. But perhaps it'll be helpful if you have native Excel as an option (if using an older version of Excel, install PowerQuery to get the same functionality): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a very helpful answer for Excel users.

Comment: For now I'll mark this as correct due to absence of other answers and that I don't require this feature anymore ;)